# Experience Form with Different Google Accounts

Tags: visual-workflow, force.com-sites, community-builder, screen-flow, experience

I have a question regarding a form I created using screen-flow in our community. I've noticed an interesting behavior when filling out the form, particularly in the first step where I'm required to enter my identification document number (government ID).

If the government ID corresponds to a contact already present in our organization, the ReadOnlyScreenComponent displays the contact's contact information. This makes sense since they are already part of the organization.

However, when I enter the same government ID using my personal Google account, the contact information does not appear. It seems like the getElement is unable to find any contact associated with that government ID. I have also tried accessing the form using an incognito window in Google, and interestingly, I can see the information there.

Could anyone help me understand why this discrepancy occurs when filling the form with different Google accounts?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain more about how your Flow works and how your Google account interacts with this form.  How are you integrating this flow with Google user accounts?  Please [edit] your post.